# Isomorphism of curves induces isomorphism of moduli spaces of vector bundles on the curves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, moduli-space

Suppose we have an isomorphism of projective curves $f : C \to C'$. Let $M_C(\mu)$ denote the moduli space of slope stable vector bundles on $C$ with slope $\mu$. Do we get an induced isomorphism $F : M_C(\mu) \to M_{C'}(f(\mu))$?

If $f_*$ is the map induced by $f$ on the level of, say, coherent sheaves (or even derived categories), then I think I can show that if $E$ is a vector bundle on $C$ then $f_*(E)$ is a vector bundle on $C'$ in my case.

However, I'm not sure what to do about slope stability. I tried the following: let $E \in M_C(\mu)$ and consider a sub-vector bundle $S \subset f_*(E)$ with slope $\mu(S) \geq \mu(f_*(E))$. Now $\mathrm{Hom}(S, f_*(E)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(f^*(S), E)$ by adjunction. Then I said something like "slope behaves well under pull-back", which would mean that $\mu(f^*(S)) \geq \mu(E)$ and by slope stability of $E$, the Hom would vanish giving slope stability of $f_*(E)$, but I think this argument is way too simplistic (i.e. I don't think the slope being preserved under pullback thing is true, because there is [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/1527/142073) on MathOverflow asking about the stability of pushforwards of line bundles on curves, and the answer seems non-trivial).

I'd be grateful for any help, or pointers to a reference if there is a simple way of proving this statement. Thanks.